# Cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.func<int>'

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement asynchronous programming into my windows forms app, and am receiving this error message when trying to return the task. I do not know how to convert an 'int' to a 'System.Func'.

I am returning an int instead of a bool because when i try to return the bool, I get an error stating asynchronous methods have to return an int or a task.

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<int> task = new Task<int>(CheckForFiles());
    task.Start();
    label1.Text = "Checking for file...";
    int FilesPresent = await task;
    if (FilesPresent == 1)
    {
        label1.Text = "file present";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "file missing";
    }

}

private int CheckForFiles()
{
    int fileExists = 0;
    bool result = File.Exists(@"FileLocation");

    if (result == true)
    {
        fileExists = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        fileExists = 0;
    }
    return (fileExists);
}
```

I expect to be able to update this method to allow for asynchronous programming to function successfully

Comment: Not sure about asynchronous execution in WinForms but the issue with your code should be fixed in that way: `Task<int> task = new Task<int>(CheckForFiles);`

Comment: There is no reason to create a task there espicially if you're not going to call an an async operation, don't create a task, but if for some reason you must create the task then make CheckForFilesAsync and call await on it4

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of the async/await pattern in .NET. Please read https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html. Basically, async/await is NOT the same as parallelism. The primary reason you want to use it is to increase scalability. The executing threads can handle other requests while *awaiting* external processes (database queries, API calls, file I/O, etc). In a single-threaded application like a single-user WinForms application, there aren't very many use cases where you need it.

Comment: Let's take a big step back here. Why are you trying to make a file-exists check asynchronous in the first place? That check is usually fast; do you have a scenario where a file-exists check is *blocking the UI thread*?  If so, **let's talk about that scenario** because that's the actually interesting problem to consider.

Comment: Also, you've got re-entrancy problems galore here. Let's suppose that there *is* a scenario where the file-exists call takes a second.  What do you do? You spawn a thread to do that call, and then *immediately return control back to the user, who is then able to click the button a dozen more times in that second*.  If you're going to make asynchronous button handlers you need to make sure that your *entire* application is robust in the face of UI stuff happening while asynchronous operations are in flight.  Give that some thought.

Comment: You are also setting yourself up for a TOCTOU defect. That is: Time Of Check is not Time Of Use.  Suppose you check to see if the file exists. Great. What stops anyone from deleting the file *after* the check?  Nothing! Or the opposite -- if the file does not exist, someone can create it after the check. Therefore the check is in some sense useless because you cannot rely upon it; you don't know that the file exists, all you know is that it existed *at the time of the check*.   What are you using this check for? You may wish to rethink this also.

Answer (score 9):

First off let me say: **you are doing this fundamentally wrong**.  You do NOT want to make a new thread to do an IO task, which is what you are trying to do.  But that's not the problem that is blocking you right now.

---

The problem with your code that you've made the common error of confusing `CheckForFiles` -- which is a *function that returns an integer* with `CheckForFiles()` which is an *execution* of the function, and therefore, an *integer*.

You do NOT want this:

```
Task<int> task = new Task<int>(CheckForFiles());
```

That is the same as

```
int result = CheckForFiles();
Task<int> task = new Task<int>(result);
```

which is plainly nonsense.  What you want is:

```
Task<int> task = new Task<int>(CheckForFiles);
```

That is **do not call the function; make a task from the function**.

Or use a lambda if the code is more complex:

```
Task<int> task = new Task<int>(() => CheckForFiles());
```

Or if you need multiple statements:

```
Task<int> task = new Task<int>(() => { return CheckForFiles(); } );
```

> I am returning an int instead of a bool because when i try to return the bool, I get an error stating asynchronous methods have to return an int or a task.

Then you are doing something else wrong too. You should be able to make `CheckForFiles` return `bool` and use a `Task<bool>`.

---

But once again **do not make a new thread to do an IO task**.  That works against the whole idea of asynchrony in windows forms, which is that we want to keep the IO tasks asynchronous *on the UI thread*. Re-think how you are adding asynchrony to your program.